Problem with assigning new "IDs" in big data frames for long data in R
I have a dataframe with around 50k rows with two columns that give two different IDs, both are two different adress data: propertys (called "LS") and Objects on the property (called "Obj").
Every property can have multiple different objects and every object is unique for one property.
Because of other data in the dataframe many objects have multiple entries (my data have 96 columns).
My LS numbers have a range of around 1600 different entries (LS_0001 to LS_1981 not all IDs are assigned) and my Objects around 3600 different entries (OBJ_0001 - OBJ_3576).
The data have the following format:
df<-data.frame(  LS=c("LS_01","LS_01","LS_01","LS_01","LS_01","LS_01","LS_02","LS_02","LS_02","LS_02","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04","LS_04"),  OBJ=c("OBJ_01","OBJ_01","OBJ_02","OBJ_02","OBJ_03","OBJ_04","OBJ_05","OBJ_05","OBJ_05","OBJ_06","OBJ_07","OBJ_07","OBJ_08","OBJ_09","OBJ_10","OBJ_11","OBJ_12","OBJ_13","OBJ_14","OBJ_15","OBJ_16","OBJ_17"))

Now I want to assign a second object number that counts the objects in one property(so every property should start with an object number of OBJ_0001). Therefore I copyed my original object number and overwritte it stepwise in a loop with following code:
df$OBJ_2<-df$OBJ

for (i in 1:length(unique(df$LS))) {
  for(j in 1:unique(length(df$OBJ_2[df$LS==unique(df$LS)[i]]))) {
    df$OBJ_2[df$OBJ_2==unique(df$OBJ_2[df$LS==unique(df$LS)[i]])[j]]<-paste("OB",sprintf("%04d",j),sep = "_")}}

table(df[,3:4])

The desired outcome for my new varible in the above sample is this:
df$des_sol<-c("OB_0001", "OB_0001", "OB_0002", "OB_0002", "OB_0003", "OB_0004", "OB_0001", "OB_0001", "OB_0001", "OB_0002", "OB_0001", "OB_0001", "OB_0002", "OB_0003", "OB_0004", "OB_0005", "OB_0006", "OB_0007", "OB_0008", "OB_0009", "OB_0010", "OB_0011")

This works fine for the above test data, there the numbers are assigned correctly. Also when I use only small subsets of my data the output is correct.  But when I run my whole dataset with all columns in it (including the ones that are not used in the code), it seems to work at the first glance but skips some Object numbers (for example always "OBJ_0002" and "OBH_0009-0011"). I cant explain where the skips are comming from because the numbers are comming from the upcounting variable coming from the loop.
In the picture you can see the result of the code run with the whole dataset shown as table. There you can see that for all LN ID`s the OBJ_0002 is skiped and for some also others (for example for LS_0012 the OBJ_0003).
When I cut my dataset for only the two columns that are used in the code (LS_ID and OBJ_ID) the outcome have less errors (all object numbers are defined) but for some LS_IDs some object numbers still are skipped.
I have the same errors when I rename the objects without the past and sprintf function only but only with a number.
Whit this information for me it seemed like there is not really an error in the code but some fundamental error in my understanding and useage of the functions.
I have tried to search for errors in the help files of the functions but didnt find anything that explains this behavior.
Does anybody know where my errors are comming from?
Thanks for the help in advance.
edit: I would like to stay in base R if possible

From the sample data you provided, what would your desired output look like? If its just to create a consecutive count of objects by LS you could use the dplyr library and do: df %>% mutate(obj_2 = paste0("OBJ_", sprintf("%04d", row_number())), .by = LS)

It seems very strange that, in your j loop definition you use unique(length(...)) instead of length(unique(...)). That seems like a bug to me.

@GregorThomas thx for the hint, I just saw it was a copy paste error, the code I used has it the other way around like you suggested it

So, your code doesn't make sense to me compared to your problem statement. I'm confused because you way "I want to assign a second object number", but your code doesn't create a new, 2nd object number, it overwrites the first one. You are dynamically (in a loop) using the original object number and also modifying it in the same process, which makes things much more complicated. That you recalculate unique(df$OBJ) in the body of the loop as you are changing df$OBJ is probably the root problem. Also, the double loop is very convoluted and inefficient compared to vectorized code.

I suspect there is a much easier way to do this. Could you please edit the question to include the desired output corresponding to the sample input? That way we can be sure of what you goal is, and probably share a much simpler way to do it.

@GregorThomas I hope I showed now better what I have done and what the desired output is that i hope for

Okay, I think df$result = ave(df$OBJ, df$LS, FUN = \(x) sprintf("OB_%04d", as.integer(factor(x)))) does what you want. I've nominated your question for re-opening so I can post that as an answer. It differs a bit from your df$des_sol in the last few rows, where you have OB_0009, OB_0001, OB_0002, but I assume you don't want to re-use those IDs and instead you want OB_0009, OB_0010, OB_0011?

@GregorThomas thanks for your help it worked your way perfectly
